# Getting strange error in custom module Magento2.4.0

Tags: magento, magento2

I have installed a custom module in Magento 2.4.0 but when I try to access it from backend then I am getting below strange error.

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (InvalidArgumentException): Either remote URL or hashable content is required to whitelist
```

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by something trying to render an asset tag to the page that doesn't have a url or hash.

If you read the stacktrace a bit more you should get an indication of where the issue is coming from.

In our case we had the module `Ebizmarts_Mailchimp` installed.
This was the exception:

```sh
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (InvalidArgumentException): Either remote URL or hashable content is required to whitelist

Exception #0 (InvalidArgumentException): Either remote URL or hashable content is required to whitelist
<pre>#1 Magento\Csp\Helper\InlineUtil\Proxy->processTag() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Helper/SecureHtmlRenderer.php:67]
#2 Magento\Framework\View\Helper\SecureHtmlRenderer->renderTag() called at [vendor/mailchimp/mc-magento2/view/frontend/templates/mailchimpjs.phtml:8]
#3 include() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/TemplateEngine/Php.php:71]
#4 Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php->render() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php:273]
#5 Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->fetchView() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php:303]
#6 Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->_toHtml() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php:1111]
...
```

Notice the `vendor/mailchimp/mc-magento2/view/frontend/templates/mailchimpjs.phtml:8` at line `#2`

The fix for us was to apply [this patch](https://github.com/zero1limited/magento2-patches/blob/eb137aaaf90ffa86add6566116d08723b1acfc26/patches/Ebizmarts_Mailchimp_mailchimpjs.patch)

If you've got [cweagans/composer-patches](https://packagist.org/packages/cweagans/composer-patches) installed you can just add this to your `composer.json`

```json
"extra": {
    "patches": {
        "mailchimp/mc-magento2":{
            "Either remote URL or hashable content is required to whitelist": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/zero1limited/magento2-patches/eb137aaaf90ffa86add6566116d08723b1acfc26/patches/Ebizmarts_Mailchimp_mailchimpjs.patch"
        }
    }
}
```

Then run `composer install --no-dev` and flush cache.

Answer (score 0):

keep it simple :

override file mailchimpjs.phtml in path of ur theme : app/design/frontend/Luma/default/Ebizmarts_MailChimp/templates/mailchimpjs.phtml

replace exist content by this :

```
$url = $block->getJsUrl();
if($url){
    $render = $block->getRender();
    echo $render->renderTag('script',['type'=>'text/javascript','src'=>$url],'',false);
}
```